# Can the fields be returned with names in a ADODB Result set for an output parameterized stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures, resultset, adodb

Although I've worked a lot with VBA over the years, I'm finding my first opportunity to use it to connect to a MS SQL database and execute a number of different queries. This issue is about having the result set returned have named fields. Currently, and after some struggle with the parameters, I've gotten my query working. It executes a parameterized stored procedure that has one input and two output parameters.

Here is the sp:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetFamily] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@FormulaNum     varchar(10),
@FamilyID       bigint OUTPUT,
@FamilyName     varchar(20) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT @FamilyID = v.FamilyID, @FamilyName = f.FamilyName FROM utblVariants as v
    INNER JOIN dbo.utblFamilies as f
    ON v.FamilyID = f.FamilyID
WHERE v.FormulaNo = @FormulaNum

SELECT @FamilyID, @FamilyName
END
```

And here is the relevant part of the VBA code:

```vb
'open the connection to the database
oConn.Open sConnString

'setup the command parameter including the sp parameters
With oCmd
    .ActiveConnection = oConn
    .CommandText = "BWDG.dbo.uspGetFamily"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    'Formul number input parameter
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@FormulaNum", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Trim(txtFromFormula.Value))
    'Formula Family ID returned as an output parameter
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@FamilyID", adBigInt, adParamOutput, , Null)
    'Formula Family name returned as an output parameter
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@FamilyName", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 20, Null)

End With

'Get the resultset from the executed connection command
oRS.Open oCmd
'Set oRS = oConn.Execute(sExecString)

If Not (oRS.EOF And oRS.BOF) Then
    oRS.MoveFirst
    'Parse the data to corresponding variables
    iFromFamilyID = oRS(0)
    sFromFamily = oRS(1)

    lblFromFamily.Caption = sFromFamily

End If
```

I would like the items in the result set oRS to return with the fields named. Currently the names of the fields are empty.
[Field Names in the result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIvX2.jpg)

This code will get reused (I'm just performing development testing currently) and I would like it to be more intuitive, not only for me, but for others who may end up maintaining this.

So, the question, is there a way to have the result set populated so the fields are named and thereby allow the item references to be the names instead of index number?

Comment: In your stored procedure, alias the columns. `SELECT @FamilyID as FamilyID, @FamilyName as FamilyName`

Comment: ^^ that. now, I'm not sure why you'd need to `select` these two values, given your parameters *already* contain the returned values - the recordset is redundant. Just declare your two out parameters as local variables instead of inlining them, and they should have their value after you run `cmd.Execute`. Also, please read [*Making wrong code look wrong*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) for why `oCmd` and `oRS` and `iFromFamilyID` and `sFromFamily` are horrible identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `out` parameters... why do you need to `select` them and return them in a recordset at all?

```vb
'...

Dim familyId As ADODB.Parameter
Dim familyName As ADODB.Parameter

With cmd
    '...
    Set familyId = .CreateParameter("@FamilyID", adBigInt, adParamOutput, , Null)
    .Paramters.Append familyId
    Set familyName = .CreateParameter("@FamilyName", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 20, Null)
    .Parameters.Append familyName

    .Execute
End With
```

And then you can retrieve the out parameter values right there:

```
lblFromFamily.Caption = familyName.Value
```

No recordset needs to get involved.

---

**Alternatively**, if you *want* to select the results and return a `Recordset`, you can do that - but then, **drop the `out` parameters**!

In that case you'll need to alias your columns, [as was already mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702168/can-the-fields-be-returned-with-names-in-a-adodb-result-set-for-an-output-parame#comment70601006_41702168).

```sql
SELECT @FamilyID FamilyID, @FamilyName FamilyName
```

(the `As` keyword can be included, optionally, if you prefer that)

And then you can retrieve the fields by name:

```vb
familyId = rs.Fields("FamilyID").Value
familyName = rs.Fields("FamilyName").Value
```

Or, using the equivalent shorthand "bang" notation (assuming column aliases are legal VBA identifiers):

```vb
familyId = rs!FamilyID
familyName = rs!FamilyName
```

Comment: This is also my first foray into writing stored procedures using output parameters so you all's questions as to why I would do that can only be answered "ignorance!" :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Your assistance was invaluable!
I will look at the above mentioned article and attempt to work more cleanly and efficiently in the future. In my defense, I'm not a pure coder (as if you didn't realize that already). My background is in industrial automation with PLC, HMI, and SCADA systems. I am getting more into the industrial software side of the business and I'm having a blast learning new things and working in new environments and with different tools and process. Thanks again for the help, YOU'RE ALL GREAT!

Comment: Sweet! Thanks Mat, I just keep showing my ignorance. I looked around for a second or two to figure that out but moved on.

Comment: Thanks! I was also using an output parameter and this solution worked for me!